# Is this simple example considered as RAII

Tags: c++, raii

And peformance-wise, are there some better ways to do that?

for example, create a class/struct called arraydata, it allocates some aligned memory for use (though a pointer provided by .dataPtr):

```
class arraydata//to allocate some memory, 
               //and return a pointer to that block of memory
{
    void *dataPtrV;

  public:

    double *dataPtr;

    arraydata(int a, int b)
    {
        dataPtrV=_aligned_malloc(a*b*sizeof(double),32);
        dataPtr=(double *)dataPtrV;
    }

    ~arraydata()
    {
        _aligned_free(dataPtrV);
        dataPtrV=NULL;
        dataPtr=NULL;
    }   
};
```

Then call it by:

```
     arraydata X(30,20);
```

Comment: Why do you use free/malloc in C++?

Comment: @Cubic: this is unfortunately the only way to get aligned storage. There are other ways to package this though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that would be considered RAII - the resource is acquired in the constructor and released in the destructor.

I'm not sure why you're storing both a `void*` and a `double*` though - only a `double*` should suffice.

Also, be extremely careful when copying your class as that will easily lead to leaks and freeing already freed data.

Anyway, this can also be done using `std::unique_ptr` which is more idiomatic and without the downfalls of your class:

```
struct aligned_free {
  void operator()(void* p) {
     _aligned_free(p);
  }
};

template<typename T>
T* aligned_malloc(std::size_t size, std::size_t alignment) {
  return static_cast<T*>(_aligned_malloc(size * sizeof(T), alignment));
}

std::unique_ptr<double, aligned_free> make_array_data(int a, int b) {
    return std::unique_ptr<double, aligned_free>(aligned_malloc<double>(a*b, 32));
}

auto arraydata = make_array_data(30, 20);
```

---

Here's your class without `void*`:

```
class arraydata//to allocate some memory, 
               //and return a pointer to that block of memory
{

  public:

    double *dataPtr;

    arraydata(int a, int b)
    {
        dataPtr=static_cast<double*>(_aligned_malloc(a*b*sizeof(double),32));
    }

    ~arraydata()
    {
        _aligned_free(dataPtr);
    }   
};
```

Comment: Thanks, as for void pointer, well, thats because the _aligned_malloc() function I called only accepts void pointer.

Comment: @user1748356 I posted your code without the `double*`. Tell me if it doesn't compile.

Comment: By casting it to double, can _aligned_free still works properly? btw, _aligned_free can only free with a void pointer so dataPtr need to be casted back, or at least I think so.

Comment: @user1748356 I am 99% sure it will work properly. The cast back to `void*` when passed to `_aligned_free` happens implicitly.

Comment: So you are 99% sure the memory allocated by _aligned_malloc() can be completely freed by _aligned_free() with a casted double pointer? there isnt much risk of memory-leaking by that?

Comment: @user1748356 With normal malloc the casting is completely fine and I can see no reason why it would be different for `_aligned_malloc`. So yes, I am sure it will be completely freed.